# How to use Dependency Injection in .NET Core 2.0 for ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ado.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using .NET Core 2.0 and ADO.NET but I am with a problem: How should I use DI for my connection string?

Before I have a DbContext (I injected it), but not anymore, since I do not use EntityFramework anymore (performance reasons).

I have 2 base projects (layers), the root site and the core project.

The root layer is only responsible for MVC. The core layer has my business and repositories logic. My repositories needs the connection string to access database via ADO.NET.

Something like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //...
}
```

I have tried some working solutions, like having a static class with a String to store my connection string, but I want to know the best approach.

Example:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services       to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
//...
}
```

Comment: The same way you DI anything else?

Comment: Also "best" is going to depend on what your goals are.  Do you even need DI?

Comment: Okay, how should I DI a string?

Comment: A string is no different than any other parameter from a DI perspective.

Comment: Have you established a need for DI in your application?  Why do you need it?

Comment: So you are telling me the best way to do it was like I did in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that my repositories should have the responsability of get the connection string

Comment: Then pass the string into the constructor when you stand up the repository.  Store it wherever you like; a static class, an Application Property, whatever.  Do that, and if you ever establish a need for DI, it can be implemented trivially later.

Comment: What is CORE? Are you refering to .NET Core?

Comment: Yes, .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I guess here is described what you want to do:

https://hackernoon.com/asp-net-core-how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-entity-framework-core-4388fc5c148b